# synchronize kinect rgb/image_color depth/image or points

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-------------------- SOLUTION -----------------
message_filters::TimeSynchronizer... has to be
message_filters::Synchronizer...
found that out after a day

---

How to mark as solved ?

Hi

I want to synchronize the image_color and the depth/image topic of a kinect.

both topics have different frequencies. i hoped before that they publish at the same time but sadly not.

is there a way to let these to topics been published simultaneously?

---

other posibility is to use a  topic with rgb and d info, but i need an easy way to get the opencv rgb image.

---

the only topic i see, which has all info is "depth/points", but I need an opencv RGB image also, an iterative loop over the pointcloud to obtain the opencv image pixel by pixel seems to be studpi, because rgb image topic already exists.

---

why doesn'T that work:

```
private:
    message_filters::Subscriber image_sub;
    message_filters::Subscriber pointcloud_sub;

    message_filters::TimeSynchronizer synchronizer;

public :

    // Constructor
    VisualAidingOpenni()
        :  nh("~")/*, it(nh)*/, synchronizer(1), ....

private:
void a function ()... {

        image_sub.subscribe(nh, topic_image, 1);
        pointcloud_sub.subscribe(nh, topic_pointcloud, 1);
        synchronizer.connectInput(image_sub, pointcloud_sub);
        synchronizer.registerCallback(boost::bind(&VisualAidingOpenni::subscriber_Callback,this , _1, _2));
}


void  subscriber_Callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& pointcloud)
    {

...
}
```

forget the word pointcloud, tried the depth image at last, so everything in sensor_msgs::image

---

this doesn't even compile

```
private:
    message_filters::Subscriber image_sub;
    message_filters::Subscriber pointcloud_sub;
    typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime MySyncPolicy;
    message_filters::TimeSynchronizer synchronizer;

void function()
{
        image_sub = new message_filters::Subscriber(nh, topic_image, 1);
        pointcloud_sub = new message_filters::Subscriber(nh, topic_pointcloud, 1);
        synchronizer = new message_filters::TimeSynchronizer(MySyncPolicy(10), image_sub, pointcloud_sub);
 synchronizer.registerCallback(boost::bind(&VisualAidingOpenni::subscriber_Callback,this , _1, _2));

}

void  subscriber_Callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& pointcloud)
    {
```

i get this error

```
/opt/hector/students/friedrich/hector_visual_aiding/hector_visaid_monocular/src/visual_aiding_openni.cpp:-1: In Elementfunktion »void VisualAidingOpenni::CamInfo_Callback(const CameraInfoConstPtr&)«:
:-1: Fehler:[CMakeFiles/visual_aiding_openni.dir/src/visual_aiding_openni.o] Fehler 1
```

THX

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42217/synchronize-kinect-rgb/image_color-depth/image-or-points/) by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-24**:
Shouldn't "mysyncpolicy" be "MySyncPolicy"?

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-24**:
i have no idea why it isn't upper case here, but it is in qtcreator

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-24**:
Also could you post the error in a codeblock, it's getting mangled.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-24**:
Yeah, there's no information on the error there.

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-24**:
well, the error message just tells me in which function i have the error, nothing more-

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-24**:
i installed 11.10 these days after i had ubuntu 12.04. since then my debugger information isn't as accurate as before, i don't know why. i use qtcreator. build type is debug.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-24**:
The build type wouldn't affect compiler errors.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-24**:
Can you try building it on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set up a callback in ROS that synchronizes messages from multiple topics with a TimeSynchronizer: http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer

As Dan Lazewatsky says in the comments below, if the timestamps aren't identical, then you might be able to use an [ApproximateTimePolicy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy) with the TimeSynchronizer.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-24**:
hi, i did that, but .. the two topics i subscribe publish in different frequencies. i need the rgb and d information as synchron as possible.

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-24**:
/camera/rgb/image_color and /camera/depth_registered/image at the same time synchron would be perfect

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-08-24**:
Since the hardware doesn't synchronize the image acquisition, there is no way to get precisely synchronized images from a kinect. Using the ApproximateTime sync policy with a time synchronizer is probably your best option.

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-24**:
so the data in /camera/depth/pointcloud with xyzrgb information is also not really synchron for positon and color ?